# Why does a ray travel in a straight line to the observer in a mirage

Tags: thermodynamics, photons, refraction

In a mirage why does the light travel in a straight line to the observer?
What name is given to a ray that bends when approaching a hot surface?

Comment: Please do some research (there are many, many sites and videos explaining how mirages work), and be more specific about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

A mirage is a naturally occurring optical phenomenon in which light rays are bent to produce a displaced image of distant objects or the sky.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage

It is called refracted light.